# Data not displaying from SQL Server database in UWP with gridview and Error when i want to use my search function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, uwp

I linked my SQL Server database to a UWP app, but now my gridview does not want to display my data.

```
string cs = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Artist;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection con;
SqlDataAdapter adapt;
DataTable dt;

// frmSearch Load Event   
private void frmSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();

    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ArtistTable", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);

    ArtistGV.ItemsSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}

private void txtsearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();

    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ArtistTable where ArtistName like '" + txtsearch.Text + "%'", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);

    ArtistGV.ItemsSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}
```

When I run the app, the data is not displayed, and when I try to use my search function I get an error on the con.Open(); in the txtsearch method. The error I am getting is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Failed to generate SSPI context.

Comment: You really need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. What you have posted is wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable **Enterprise Authentication** capability in you **Package.appxmanifest**.

Double click the file in **Solution Explorer**, go to capabilities tab and check the box next to **Enterprise Authentication.**

You can see a related `corefx` issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24336).

Alternatively change the server to use username and password and set `Integrated Security=false`

Comment: now on the ArtistGV.ItemsSource = dt; line I get an error System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

Comment: Okay in this case it is because you cannot directly bind `DataTable` to `ItemsSource`. `ItemsSource` expects a collection or array, so you will first have to create a class that represents an `Artist`, then create an array of artists from the `DataTable` and then assign that to `ItemsSource`. Alternatively try the `DataGrid` control I mentioned on the previous question. It might actually support `DataTable`.

Comment: Good thing is now you actually have data in the `DataTable` so this should now be going well :-).